Detailed derivation of electric field in anisotropic media in literature
Is there a proper and detailed derivation of the electric field inside a linear and anisotropic (but homogenous, dispersionless and lossless) medium in the literature? Most sources I could find (and my study material) normally end at the fact that one can always choose the susceptibility tensor to be diagonal:
$$ \vec{P} = \epsilon_0 \mathrm{diag}(\chi_1, \chi_2, \chi_3) \vec{E} $$
Next, they suddenly discuss the index ellipsoid. But there are of course a few steps missing, starting with the expansion of the field, solution of the wave equation and most importantly, discussion of the solution. What happens if the field is not polarized parallel to the principal axes of the crystal? Because here, the next equation is just the relationship between the refractive indices, but not where the angle dependence comes form and how it is connected to the polarization.
I am looking mainly for resouces such as book suggestions, papers etc.

"Fundamentals of Photonics" by Saleh & Teich has an excellent treatment of propagation in linear anisotropic media in ch. 6. The wave equation is not explicitly solved, but the reason for this is that it's a trivial step. When the permittivity tensor is diagonalised you obtain three independent wave equations, one for each electric-field component. You can therefore immediately see that the solutions are waves propagating at $c/\sqrt{\epsilon_i / \epsilon_0}$. Through the linearity of Maxell's equations, propagation of an arbitrary polarisation can be decomposed into superpositions of these.
